# Масштабирование страницы при изменении разрешения

Tags: масштабирование, javascript, css

Добрый день, о лучшие умы планеты!

Есть задача, при изменении разрешения экрана, контент уменьшать пропорционально (все внутри страницы, оставлять на местах, только уменьшать). Нагуглил про тему viewport

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1376px) {
@-ms-viewport { width: 1920px; }
```

Но это работает только в опере и эксплорер. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно добиться кроссбраузерного эффекта как у viewport?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю на сколько это вам поможет, есть плагин [jquery.fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Плагин реализует как раз маштабирование контента. Я конектил к нему стили bootstrap все работает.

Comment: Спасибо за участие, но это не то =( Мне нужно при изменении размеров окна браузера, пропорционально уменьшать элементы. Как будто все единая картинка, и картинка пропорционально уменьшается.